# Query function from 2 Tabs into an accounting sheet with two date columns - Query doesn't work as it can't find the columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm querying data from two tabs within a sheet to give an overview of an inventory

Two of the columns (AI & AQ) are dates - I'm struggling through my rookieness to even get it working.

Any suggestion?

The Query is below:
=QUERY({'Position Live'!B10:AS;'Delivered Archive'!B8:AS}, "SELECT
AI,AP,D,Y,K,J,E,AL,AK,F,G,I,AJ,Q,R,AG,AH,AQ where AM Contains 'Done'")

With the above formula, the return is "AI doesn't exist"

If i convert the columns to:
=QUERY({'Position Live'!B10:AS;'Delivered Archive'!B8:AS}, "SELECT Col35,Col42,Col4,Col25,Col11,Col10,Col5,Col38,Col37,Col6,Col7,Col9,Col36,Col17,Col18,Col33,Col34,Col43 where Col39 Contains 'Done'")
it returns "Query Completed with an empty output"

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 0):

you are using array `{'Position Live'!B10:AS;'Delivered Archive'!B8:AS}` which means your query must use `Col` references

Comment: I tried that too with - 
    =QUERY({'Position Live'!B10:AS;'Delivered Archive'!B8:AS}, "SELECT Col35,Col42,Col4,Col25,Col11,Col10,Col5,Col38,Col37,Col6,Col7,Col9,Col36,Col17,Col18,Col33,Col34,Col43 where Col39 Contains 'Done'")
it returns "Query Completed with an empty output"

Comment: @GregorCarswell can you share a copy/sample of your sheet?